# Java logging framework - with printf() support

Tags: java, logging, log4j, printf

In c, `printf()` is really easy to use, and in Java `System.out.printf()` is also amazing, but in `log4j`, seems only can use `"First name: "+ firstName +", Age: " + age`, which is very uncomfortable.

**The questions are:**

- What is the difficulty that prevents `log4j` from implement such a feature?
- What logging framework support such feature, can u give a short example that include the maven dependencies & Java code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`org.slf4j.Logger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) which *provides* a way to format `log` in such manner.

For example,

```
LOGGER.info("Roll number of Student {} is {}.", studentName, rollNumber);
```

Comment: Nice, I just did a test, with `slf4j-api 1.7.13`, method `info(String format, Object... arguments)` works similar as `printf()` with info logging level, with 1 exception that it add a new line automatically, thus `\n` is not required.

Answer (score 5):

You could use String's [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method like:

```
logger.info(String.format("Student %s with roll number %d found!", studentName, rollNumber));
```

Comment: this is less preferable than using slf4j because the string has to get formatted before being passed into the info method (and possibly getting filtered out depending on the log config), so it does a lot of possibly unnecessary work.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good option, but I am wondering if it's so easy why log4j never provider a wrapper method like that...

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes it does. But in slf4j's [format](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.java) is more complex and memory intensive in terms of string's format method. See that it expects array as parameters.

Comment: @SMA I just checked `slf4j-api 1.7.13`, it provide a variable length argument list, not just a single array.

Comment: Really? I am not sure. But if that's true, even in underling c `printf()` use a varargs, so I think it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the parameterized logging discussed by others Log4j 2 supports

LOGGER.printf(Level.INFOR, format, parm1);

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html#Mixing_Loggers_with_Formatter_Loggers.

FWIW, Log4j also supports logging using strings that conform to java.text.MessageFormat and java.util.Formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Use log4j2's LogManager.getFormatterLogger to make it happy.

see: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html#Formatting_Parameters

org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager#getFormatterLogger

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.